# Delete time series metrics Prometheus by certain time period

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I've read on https://www.shellhacks.com/prometheus-delete-time-series-metrics/ that it's possible to delete time series metrics we don't need on Prometheus.

But is there anyway to remove them by certain time period; say remove metrics during Mon-Fri 5PM to 6AM etc?

Answer (score 4):

From Prometheus official documentation for the TSDB admin APIs:

> URL query parameters:
>
> - match[]=: Repeated label matcher argument that selects the series to delete. At least one match[] argument must be
>     provided.
> - start=: Start timestamp. Optional and defaults to minimum possible time.
> - end=: End timestamp. Optional and defaults to maximum possible time.
>
> Not mentioning both start and end times would clear all the data for
>   the matched series in the database.

Refer [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#delete-series)

Answer (score 3):

As per the reply above, you can check the Docs. You can also use this swagger spec: https://stoic-kare-8f0c7d.netlify.app/#/TSDB%20Admin%20API/deleteSeriesPOST

to generate your cURL, otherwise modify the example cURL provided below:

```
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series?match[]={__name__=~".+"}&start=2021-01-01T07:30:00+00:00&end=2021-01-01T22:30:00+00:00
```

Mind that the match above will delete everything, that is every time series that was stored.
Probably what you are after is a cronjob that run a script with the cURL above modified accordingly with the `match` that you want and the `start` and `end` date that match your time period.

After that remember to run

```
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/clean_tombstones
```

To actually remove the data.

Comment: this gave me a parsing error:     curl -X POST -g 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series?match[]={job="myjob"}&end=2022-10-24T18:00:00+00:00'
{"status":"error","errorType":"bad_data","error":"Invalid time value for 'end': cannot parse \"2022-10-24T18:00:00 00:00\" to a valid timestamp"}

Comment: that's what the error says. Wrong timestamp format

Comment: Plus sign (`+`) means space in URL encoding. Use `%2B` instead of it: `2021-01-01T07:30:00+00:00` -> `2021-01-01T07:30:00%2B00:00`.

Comment: After 2 hours this is the solution... thanks

Answer (score 1):

On RPI with RPI OS and curl I have to use the following format:

e.g. Zulu time:

```
curl -X POST -g 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series?match[]={job="myjob"}&start=2022-10-20T07:30:00Z&end=2022-10-24T18:00:00Z'
```

e.g. for +2hours

```
curl -X POST -g 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series?match[]={job="myjob"}&start=2022-10-20T07:30:00%2B02:00&end=2022-10-26T14:15:00%2B02:00'
```

[https://groups.google.com/g/prometheus-users/c/hcM2uKKCrSA[see][1]](https://groups.google.com/g/prometheus-users/c/hcM2uKKCrSA%5Bsee%5D%5B1%5D)

Comment: Server should be started with the `--web.enable-admin-api` option, so that the `delete_series` API will be available.